# Upper bound to a symmetric function

Tags: inequality

Let $ g(\cdot)$ be a symmetric function about 0 that always is positive, i.e. $g(x)=g(-x)$ and $g(x)>0$.

Could someone explain why we then have:
$$g(x) \leq g(0)+\frac{1}{2}(\sup|g''|)x^2$$

Edit:
Assuming sufficient differntiability

Comment: I doubt this is true without additional assumptions. For example, $g''$ may not even exist.

Comment: *If* all those derivatives exist: What can you say about $g'(0)$? Then apply Taylor's theorem.

Comment: Assuming that $g''$ exists, you should try with Taylor.

Comment: @MPW We assume that g'' exists and is finite that is kinda inherent to the question. Can you come up with any other reason for why this might be wrong?

Comment: Would not applying taylors theorem add a error term that could be negative?

Comment: So you must then add the hypothesis that $g$ is (at least) twice differentiable. In fact, most (both in a topological and a measure-theoretic sense) continuous functions are nowhere differentiable, let alone twice differentiable. That said, of course I understand that you intend that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helpful comments, answer is relatively straightforward... From symmetry have that $g'(x)=-g'(-x)$  this gives $g'(0)=0$ and so by taylors theorem:
$$g(x) = g(0)+\frac{1}{2}g''(\xi)x^2\leq g(0)+\frac{1}{2}\sup |g''|x^2$$
For some $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$.